# How to convert a PySpark Notebook to a job

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have currently a PySpark notebook in Azure synapse with many Dataframe transformations and `display()` statements. Running the notebook takes a while due to these job collections of the `display()` statements. Now I want to create a `.py` file and a PySpark job. I don‘t find information about that.

Can I move all the Dataframe transformations to a .py file and create the job definition or is there more to think about?

BR

Comment: can you provide sample data code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce to create spark job definition in Azure synapse.
As you mentioned you want the .Py file to PySpark job.

For example, I have created the `wordcount.py` and `shakespeare.txt`  and uploaded to the ADLS.

**Step 1:**
Upload the .py file to ADLS storage account.
[image]

**Step 2:** Create a new Spark job definition
[image]

**Step 3:** In spark job defination page Provide langauge as Python.
[image]

**Step 4:** Provide the name for your spark job definition and fill in the details.

In the **Main definition file** provide the fully qualified path of The**.py** file which is in the ADLS storage account.

Below images shows navigation to the ABFSS path
[image]
[image]

Provide the ABFSS path in spark job definition in the **Main definition file** section.
[image]

**Step 5:** Now you can publish to save the Apache Spark job definition.
[image]

**Step 6:** Submit your spark Job definition
Go to develop hub and find your spark job definition and click on submit.

[image]

**Step 7:** Once the spark job is submitted. You will see a spark monitoring URL.
[image]

Clicking the above url will show your job status.
[image]

**Step 8:** check the output in the ADLS
[image]

as you mentioned if we can move all the Dataframe transformations to a .py file
For example, here is the Pyspark dataframes with some sample Transformation:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SampleNotebook").getOrCreate()
data = [("Alice", 28), ("Bob", 22), ("Charlie", 35), ("David", 29)]
columns = ["Name", "Age"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
print("Initial DataFrame:")
df.show()
filtered_df = df.filter(df.Age > 25)
transformed_df = filtered_df.withColumn("AgePlusFive", filtered_df.Age + 5)
print("Transformed DataFrame:")
transformed_df.show()
```

The .py file looks like this.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SampleJob").getOrCreate()
    data = [("Alice", 28), ("Bob", 22), ("Charlie", 35), ("David", 29)]
    columns = ["Name", "Age"]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
    filtered_df = df.filter(df.Age > 25)
    transformed_df = filtered_df.withColumn("AgePlusFive", filtered_df.Age + 5)
    transformed_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("synapse/destination")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have used the above .py file and ran the spark job it got succeed.
[image]